# Find all char excluding group at the end with regexp

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have this string:

```
this is a test
```

at the end of this string I have a space and the new line.
I want to extract (for counting) all space group in the string witout the last space.
With my simple regex

```
/\s+/g
```

I obtain these groups:

```
this(1)is(2)a(3)test(4)
```

I want to exclude from group the forth space because i want to get only 3 groups if the string end with space.
What is the correct regexp?

Comment: `\s+(?!$)` ........

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/uH3wG0/1

Comment: `\h(?!$)` ..... :-)

Comment: \s+(?!$)  is the best, but I don't want the last group if I add more spaces at the end.

Comment: @davymartu: See my answer. It would be great to know what regex flavor you are using though.

Comment: @wiktor I'm using Javascript falvor regex

Comment: Good, I suggested 2 ways to work around the lack of possessive quantifiers in JS. BTW, if leading spaces are not to be considered, you could just use `.trim()` before counting spaces with `\s+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the regex flavor, you can use two approaches.

If atomic groups/possessive quantifiers are not supported, use a lookahead solution like this:

```
(?:\s(?!\s*$))+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO7wT2/3)

The main point is that we only match a whitespace that is not followed with 0+ other whitespace symbols followed with an end of string (the check if performed with the `(?!\s*$)` lookahead).

Else, use

```
\s++(?!$)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO7wT2/2). An equivalent expression with an atomic groups is `(?>\s+)(?!$)`.

Here, we check for the end of string position ONLY after grabbing all whitespaces without backtracking into the `\s++` pattern (so, if after the last space there is an end of string, the whole match is failed).

Also, it is possible to emulate an atomic group in JavaScript with the help of capturing inside the positive lookahead and then using a backreference like

```
(?=(\s+))\1(?!$)
```

However, [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/hO7wT2/4) is costly in terms of performance.